# Line endings in a form textarea

Tags: php, html

Morning,

When you post a form which has a textarea, what line endings are used?
\r\n, \n or like local files does it depend on the OS?

I am tryring to find an RFC or W3C spec or something, or is it different based on OS/browser? Got a link?

eg

```
<textarea name="message">This is
my
message
</textarea>
```

Would it be

```
This is\r\n
my\r\n
message\r\n
```

or

```
This is\n
my\n
message\n
```

and is it a standard or different based on browser/os. Proof?

I am not worried about the textarea content before it's sent to the server, but the actual variable contents in PHP/server side.

Comment: When it stores in the DB, I need it to be consistant, so if a user on windows with IE saves something, it needs to have the same line endings as Linux with FireFox. I know locally there are different line endings, but when you submit a form the line endings on the textarea are the same I believe - I just can't find a spec/standard for this.

Comment: Just had a project and the content of the textarea in all browsers (IE7 to Chrome to FF and Safari) across all OS (Win XP - Win 8, Mac OS 10.5 - 10.9) behaved the same without doing something special. Using jQuery to submit asynchronously (I doubt there's some magic going on) and MySQL as DB engine with `utf8_unicode_ci` as column collation. We store the content without modification and write it back in a textarea on request. No problems up until now. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This information can found in the HTML5 spec. It says that for the [textarea](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-textarea-element) element:

> ... there is the form submission value. It is normalized so that line
>   breaks use U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN "CRLF" (U+000A) character pairs, and
>   in addition, if necessary given the element's wrap attribute,
>   additional line breaks are inserted to wrap the text at the given
>   width.
>
> The element's value is defined to be the element's raw value with the
>   following transformation applied:
>
> Replace every occurrence of a "CR" (U+000D) character not followed by a "LF" (U+000A) character, and every occurrence of a "LF" (U+000A)
>   character not preceded by a "CR" (U+000D) character, by a
>   two-character string consisting of a U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN "CRLF"
>   (U+000A) character pair.
>
> If the element's wrap attribute is in the Hard state, insert U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN "CRLF" (U+000A) character pairs into the string
>   using a UA-defined algorithm so that each line has no more than
>   character width characters. For the purposes of this requirement,
>   lines are delimited by the start of the string, the end of the string,
>   and U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN "CRLF" (U+000A) character pairs.

Comment: You kinda mangled the crucial part of that quote. Here's the correct version: "It is normalized so that line breaks use U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A LINE FEED (CRLF) character pairs"

Comment: @user98761 - No I didn't mangle it. That's [what it said](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#the-textarea-element). It's just the perils of linking to a living standard. I agree that what the standard says now is better worded.

Answer (score 2):

By [HTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.2), a line break is represented as CR LF. In the default data format in form submission, it is represented encoded as `%0D%0A`. (This does not depend on the operating system and its native line ending conventions.) Your server-side code will take it from there. In PHP, you will see it as `\r\n`.

Answer (score -1):

you will receive plain text - if u need to add `<br>` tags you can use
http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php =)

It's probably \n because when u dump it it return text line by line like when you use `echo "something\nsomething";`

Comment: Yes it will be plain text, but when it's stored in the DB will it be \n or \r\n ? Need something more than probably sorry :)